# EF code first- alter data after finished loading from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ado.net, ef-code-first

I have an EF code first entity, and would like to make a calculated column on it. I need all the existing db-loaded values to be finished first, so I cant fire this off a property set call. Is there an event or some way the object can know it is finished loading all the data from the db, so the calculations can be performed?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at LazyLoading which will determine when and how the data is actually retrieved. As a default the data is loaded when you first call for it. Meaning if you were to do something like this.

```
var result = DB.where(x+> x.id == 1);
```

The fields of result will be loaded as you call them like so:

```
var test = result.1stField; //1st field values will actually be loaded as this call is made.
```

You can however set it so that all data is loaded at once when you first make the call, Which should block execution until all values are loaded, which would give you the timing needed to perform your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ObjectMaterialized event is what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized.aspx